# searchBarSearchButtonClicked url return nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set up a simple tableview with a searchbar but in my function searchBarSearchButtonClicked the url constant return nil so the urlRequest can't load.

Thank you for helping.

```
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    var text = searchBar.text
    text = text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/#q=\(text)")
    let req = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    wv.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)
}
```

Comment: which text you entered ?

Comment: it should be something with your text, because let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/#q=test") is not returning nil

Comment: i got url using your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `"q=\(text)"` becomes `"q=Optional(your text here)"` because `text` is a `String?` and not a plain `String`. You can unwrap it or use a default value with `?? ""` to avoid it:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/#q=\(text ?? "")")
```

---

Additionally you have to URL encode your parameters in order to use them in a URL:

```
let searchQuery = "What's the meaning of life and everything"
let encodedQuery = searchQuery.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/#q=\(encodedQuery)")!
```

---

You can also use `URLComponents` class to compose a safe URL.

```
let searchQuery = "What's the meaning of life and everything"

var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://www.google.com")
urlComponents?.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: searchQuery)
]

let url = urlComponents?.url!
```

---

To avoid crashes in runtime, it's better to not use force unwrapping optionals `!`, and use `if let` or `guard let` to unwrap them:

```
if let url = urlComponents?.url {
    let req = URLRequest(url: url)
    wv.loadRequest(req)
}
```